# Protect an Android app using hash of signature

Tags: java, android

Using the code below I have 2 hashes for debug and release signatures. Only an app with my hashes should be allowed access to the server.

I tried to install a cracked version on my phone and on my server. In the logs I have found which cracked version has the same hash as my release signature. I analyzed the code of cracked version, crackers even did not change a function which calculates final URL for the server.

Does it mean they used my signature for cracked version of app with removed ads? As I understand crackers should use their own signature to sign a cracked app, but is this not true? Definitely they do not have access to my Keystore. I found this way to protect app in the one article, but it seems it is not a good way.

**How can I identify a cracked version?**

```
public static String getSignature(Context context) {
    String apkSignature = null;
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            context.getPackageName(),
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
        );
        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            apkSignature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("DEBUG", "SIGNATURE: " + apkSignature);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return apkSignature;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. No matter what checks you put in, when your app is cracked, those checks will be removed and replaced with code that always returns the "correct" result.

Comment: My app sends hash to the server when requests video streaming URL, if hash in the request is not correct, server returns error. So if cracker removes those checks, server will return error. My app has only content which is provided by server. No local content.

Comment: @Anton When the cracker removes those checks, they'll replace them with code that sends the server the hash you're expecting, so your server will be none the wiser.

Comment: I have found cracker uses APKSignatureKiller